# Expanding (edef) a lipsum command?

Tags: expansion

Just trying to debug some stuff, and I thought about 'expanding' a `\lipsum[1-2]` statement using `\edef` into a new command (that would contain the "raw" text); strangely I cannot get it to work; this example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

% \lipsum[1-2] % works fine

\edef\mycommand{\lipsum[1-2]}
\mycommand

\end{document}
```

... crashes with:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\GenericError  ...                                
                                                    #4  \errhelp \@err@     ...
l.9 \edef\mycommand{\lipsum
                           [1-2]}
```

How would I go about "unpacking" the 'contents' of the `\lipsum` command into a new command?

Thanks in advance for any answers,
Cheers!

Comment: I am not sure of your intent. Wouldn't simply `\def\mycommand{\lipsum[1-2]}` be enough?

Comment: Well, I am trying to basically use `\lipsum[1-2]` as an argument to another command; and that one apparently crashes at the bracket `[`; so I though, well, I'll just "extract the contents" into a new command without arguments, and then I'd use that.. `\def` does indeed work, but seemingly it will not expand down to the actual words contained in the \lipsum - I'm suspecting that would be the way to go if I want to cheat that original problem. Thanks for the feedback @Gonzalo Medina - cheers!

Comment: If it crashes at the bracket try to put the argument in extra braces, e.g. `{\lipsum[1-2]}`.

Comment: Many years later: `\unpacklipsum` is now in the package `lipsum` by default -- just refer to the documentation. And the internal macros as mentioned below no longer exist.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can't use `\edef` for commands accepting optional arguments; or, at least, not in this way. The paragraphs are stored in commands called

```
\lipsum@i
\lipsum@ii
\lipsum@iii
```

and so on. You can emulate your `\edef` by

```
\makeatletter
\def\unpacklipsum#1#2#3{%
  \count@=#1\relax
  \advance\count@\m@ne
  \def#3{}%
  \loop\ifnum\count@<#2\relax
    \advance\count@\@ne
    \edef#3{#3\csname lipsum@\romannumeral\count@\endcsname}%
  \repeat}
\makeatother
```

Then `\unpacklipsum{1}{2}{\mycommand}` will do what you need: this will store in `\mycommand` the paragraphs from 1 to 2. Paragraph number 42 can be stored in `\mycommand` with

```
\unpacklipsum{42}{42}{\mycommand}
```

Comment: Many, many thanks @egreg - exactly the kind of explanation I needed :) Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

And here I just wanted to post a supplement to this question - so as to those wandering what the use of this is. Have you ever tried striking out a lipsum paragraph? Both ulem's `\sout{\lipsum[1]}` and soul's `\so{\lipsum[1]}` would fail (the first specially because of not being able to deal with embedded `\par`s).

So, thanks to the [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/26808/2595), here is a piece of code that will properly typeset a `\lipsum` paragraph with ulem's `\sout` (*soul's `\so` also works, but the words seem stretched - it can be directly replaced in the below MWE if you want to see its effects, too*):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{soul}
% \usepackage{trace}

\makeatletter
\def\rempar #1\par{#1}
\def\unpacklipsum#1#2#3{%
  \count@=#1\relax
  \advance\count@\m@ne
  \def#3{}%
  \loop\ifnum\count@<#2\relax
    \advance\count@\@ne
%     \traceon
    \edef#3{#3\csname lipsum@\romannumeral\count@\endcsname}%
  \repeat}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

% unpack a lipsum paragraph
\unpacklipsum{2}{2}{\mycommand}
% remove the \par token at end (hopefully) using `\rempar`:
\edef\tmpx{\expandafter\rempar\mycommand}
% check if the actual lipsum text appears in terminal
\typeout{\meaning\tmpx}

% typeset a working "\sout{\lipsum[2]}":
\expandafter\sout\expandafter{\tmpx}

\end{document}
```

Comment: If you want no `\par` at the end, just load `lipsum` with the `nopar` option. Then `\unpacklipsum{2}{2}\tmp\expandafter\sout\expandafter{\tmp}` will work.