# Is there an equivalent of lipsum for shorter sections of text?

Tags: examples

The sections of text generated by [`lipsum`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/lipsum) are generally several lines long. Is there a simple way to generate shorter segments of random (generic) text (other than typing it, of course)?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This is a home brewed macro called `\loremlines`. Call as `\loremlines{number of lines}`. Note differences in multi column texts.

```
% Split a box into two
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum,multicol}
\begin{document}
\newbox\one
\newbox\two
\long\def\loremlines#1{%
    \setbox\one=\vbox {%
       Test.\footnote{a footnote}%
      \lipsum\footnote{Another footnote.}%
     }
   \setbox\two=\vsplit\one to #1\baselineskip
   \unvbox\two}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\small
\loremlines{16}
\end{multicols}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\small
\loremlines{16}
\end{multicols}
\loremlines{5}
\end{document}
```

The code works by placing the contents of a `\lipsum` command in a box and then splitting it, at `n\baselineskip`, where **n** is the number of lines.

Comment: This is fantastic! When I apply this to an itemized list, it changes the alignment of the bullets. Is there any way to keep this from happening?

Comment: @MikeL I am sure there is a way. Don't you want to pose this as a new question, people like David Carlisle can provide a more skillful answer.

Answer (score 26):

You could copy and paste paragraphs of the desired length from http://www.blindtextgenerator.com/. Obviously, this is no LaTeX or packaged version.

---

Btw, if you'd want to stick with `lipsum`, it seems to me that `\lipsum[66]` and `\lipsum[75]` are the shortest paragraphs, each generating almost exactly four lines with `article` standard settings.

Here's how I counted the lines:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum,lineno}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\lips@par}% patching lipsum's the end-of-paragraph command
        {\par\section{~~\the\c@linenumber}%extra space for ToC
        \resetlinenumber}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\linenumbers\noindent
\lipsum[1-150]

\end{document}
```

And then I went through the ToC by hand, i.e. by eye. LuaTeX probably could've done it automatically.

Comment: ... and has moreorless the same functionality as http://lipsum.org/

Comment: @tohecz: Yes, but a cleaner interface `:)`

Comment: "*...it seems to me that \lipsum[66] and \lipsum[75] are the shortest paragraphs...*" and that is why I love internet. A brave soul has already gone through at least 75 paragraphs of lorem ipsum to find the shortest paragraphs. Thank you dear brother/sister.

Comment: What on earth is a "paragraph range"? Why didn't they just set it up so we can select a number of lines?

Comment: @user32882 Where does it say paragraph range? As for your second question, `lipsum` always produces exactly the same text, no matter what your document is like. Outputting a certain number of lines, on the other hand, would be highly dependent on your font, font size, line width etc. and thus be a lot more complex to program.

Comment: @doncherry I'd argue that a correct and user friendly implementation of a lorem-ipsum package should take that into consideration. Extremely counterintuitive for a package user to think in terms of "paragraph ranges"

Comment: @user32882 As for user-friendliness – I don't disagree with that, and you're welcome to implement such a package. Don't forget that LaTeX packages are typically programmed by volunteers in their spare time!

Answer (score 16):

The [blindtext](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/blindtext)-package offers some optional settings:

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[pangram]{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\Blindtext[5][3]%5 paragraphs, each 3 pangrams
\end{document}
```

Remark: The pangram option was introduced this January 2012 with version 2.0. Maybe you need an update.

Comment: The package doesn't work as advertised: it prints whole Lorem Ipsum paragraphs regardless of options.

Comment: @EvanAad Do you use babel and define a language? (If yes: which language?) The option pangram is ignored if you determine no language. Then it uses Lorem Ipsum as a fall back.

Comment: No, I didn't use babel. Is babel a requirement for using blindtext?

Comment: blindtext is language sensitive. Without a defined language some feature use default texts. In your case, pangram has no short texts and so you get a long text.

Comment: OK, now it works, but every time I use it I get a different paragraph, even if the option is the same.

Answer (score 5):

Building upon the answer of @YiannisLazarides - if you want to use a shorter lipsum text in, say, a caption: you can "[expand](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/26808/2595)" the lipsum text, and then you can use the `xstring` package to obtain a substring for a given length of characters from that; called it `\loremnchars`, where `\loremnchars[5]{255}` will return first 255 characters of the 5th paragraph (`\lipsum[5]`):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[nopar]{lipsum}
\usepackage{xstring}
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/26808/2595
\makeatletter
\def\unpacklipsum#1#2#3{%
  \count@=#1\relax
  \advance\count@\m@ne
  \def#3{}%
  \loop\ifnum\count@<#2\relax
    \advance\count@\@ne
    \edef#3{#3\csname lipsum@\romannumeral\count@\endcsname}%
  \repeat}
\makeatother

\def\loremnchars[#1]#2{%
  \unpacklipsum{#1}{#1}{\myunpacked}%
  \StrMid{\myunpacked}{1}{#2}% same as \StrLeft{\myunpacked}{#2}
}

\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\captionof{figure}[justmy]{Just my image; \loremnchars[5]{255} ...}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Good solution. It might need a `\protect` in the caption though.