# Correct clipping of 3D tikz for adjustbox?

Tags: tikz-pgf, 3d, path-clipping

Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[%
12pt,
journal,
onecolumn,
twoside,
draftcls,
letterpaper,
]{IEEEtran}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{3d}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{setspace} %\singlespacing
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[nopar]{lipsum}
\usepackage{xstring}
% http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/26808/2595
\makeatletter
\def\unpacklipsum#1#2#3{%
  \count@=#1\relax
  \advance\count@\m@ne
  \def#3{}%
  \loop\ifnum\count@<#2\relax
    \advance\count@\@ne
    \edef#3{#3\csname lipsum@\romannumeral\count@\endcsname}%
  \repeat}
\makeatother
% http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/168754/2595
\def\loremnchars[#1]#2{%
  \unpacklipsum{#1}{#1}{\myunpacked}%
  \StrMid{\myunpacked}{1}{#2}% same as \StrLeft{\myunpacked}{#2}
}

\begin{document}

\loremnchars[1]{255} ...

\begin{center}
\singlespacing
\begin{adjustbox}{width=0.9\textwidth}
\def\angl{70}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  x={({cos(\angl)*1cm},{sin(\angl)*1cm})},y={(1.0cm,0cm)},z={(0,1cm)},
  every node/.append style={
    %xslant=0.0,yslant=0.0,
    transform shape,
  },
]

  \tikzstyle{rr} = [draw,fill=gray,opacity=0.5];

%   \node[] (tt) at (33,22) {};    %L1
%   \clip (0,0) rectangle (16,27); %L2

  \begin{scope}[canvas is yx plane at z=0.0]
    \draw[rr] (0,0) rectangle (15,27);
    \node[draw,align=left,anchor=south west] at (3,3.5) {\loremnchars[6]{60} \\ \loremnchars[7]{60}};
  \end{scope}

  \begin{scope}[canvas is yx plane at z=2.0]
    \draw[rr] (0,0) rectangle (15,27);
    \node[] (tdrag) at (7,24) {};
    \begin{scope}[shift={(tdrag)},
    rotate=180,
    anchor=center,
    transform shape,
    ]
      \node[draw,align=left] {\loremnchars[2]{60} \\ \loremnchars[3]{60}};
    \end{scope}
  \end{scope}

  \begin{scope}[canvas is yx plane at z=4.0]
    \draw[rr] (0,0) rectangle (15,27);
    \node[draw,align=left,anchor=south west] at (3,5.5) {\loremnchars[8]{60} \\ \loremnchars[9]{60}};
  \end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{adjustbox}
\captionof{figure}[short]{
A short message; \loremnchars[5]{255} ...
}
\label{fig:test}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

When the lines marked `%L1` and `%L2` are commented, as in the MWE, I get the image in the page as expected (click for full-size):

[image: test11]

Unfortunately, I have a bunch of nodes like `%L1`, laying outside the 3d scopes, which mess up the `adjustbox` margin calculation. So, since I need those nodes, I thought - maybe I can clip without removing those nodes. Unfortunately again, when I try doing that - by uncommenting the `%L1` and `%L2` lines in the MWE above - then I get a messed up clip, and the influence of the node is still visible:

[image: test12]

So my question is - how can I clip the `tikzpicture`, so the node `%L1` remains, and yet I still obtain the same margins & perspective as on the first screenshot?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are deliberate, you can use `pgfinterruptboundingbox`

```
   \begin{pgfinterruptboundingbox}
   \node[] (tt) at (33,22) {};    %L1
   \end{pgfinterruptboundingbox}
```

Full code:

```
\documentclass[%
12pt,
journal,
onecolumn,
twoside,
draftcls,
letterpaper,
]{IEEEtran}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{3d}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{setspace} %\singlespacing
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[nopar]{lipsum}
\usepackage{xstring}
% http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/26808/2595
\makeatletter
\def\unpacklipsum#1#2#3{%
  \count@=#1\relax
  \advance\count@\m@ne
  \def#3{}%
  \loop\ifnum\count@<#2\relax
    \advance\count@\@ne
    \edef#3{#3\csname lipsum@\romannumeral\count@\endcsname}%
  \repeat}
\makeatother
% http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/168754/2595
\def\loremnchars[#1]#2{%
  \unpacklipsum{#1}{#1}{\myunpacked}%
  \StrMid{\myunpacked}{1}{#2}% same as \StrLeft{\myunpacked}{#2}
}

\begin{document}

\loremnchars[1]{255} ...

\begin{center}
\singlespacing
\begin{adjustbox}{width=0.9\textwidth}
\def\angl{70}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  x={({cos(\angl)*1cm},{sin(\angl)*1cm})},y={(1.0cm,0cm)},z={(0,1cm)},
  every node/.append style={
    %xslant=0.0,yslant=0.0,
    transform shape,
  },
]

  \tikzstyle{rr} = [draw,fill=gray,opacity=0.5];
   \begin{pgfinterruptboundingbox}
   \node[] (tt) at (33,22) {};    %L1
   \end{pgfinterruptboundingbox}
%   \clip (0,0) rectangle (16,27); %L2

  \begin{scope}[canvas is yx plane at z=0.0]
    \draw[rr] (0,0) rectangle (15,27);
    \node[draw,align=left,anchor=south west] at (3,3.5) {\loremnchars[6]{60} \\ \loremnchars[7]{60}};
  \end{scope}

  \begin{scope}[canvas is yx plane at z=2.0]
    \draw[rr] (0,0) rectangle (15,27);
    \node[] (tdrag) at (7,24) {};
    \begin{scope}[shift={(tdrag)},
    rotate=180,
    anchor=center,
    transform shape,
    ]
      \node[draw,align=left] {\loremnchars[2]{60} \\ \loremnchars[3]{60}};
    \end{scope}
  \end{scope}

  \begin{scope}[canvas is yx plane at z=4.0]
    \draw[rr] (0,0) rectangle (15,27);
    \node[draw,align=left,anchor=south west] at (3,5.5) {\loremnchars[8]{60} \\ \loremnchars[9]{60}};
  \end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{adjustbox}
\captionof{figure}[short]{
A short message; \loremnchars[5]{255} ...
}
\label{fig:test}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

But remember that the bounding box is not adjusted to be within the page and with the coordinate you are giving to `L1` (ie, `(tt)`), if you put any content in node `(tt)`, it will go out of the page.

As noted by percusse, adding `overlay` option does the same.

```
\node[overlay] (tt) at (33,22) {};    %L1
```

Comment: Many thanks for that, @HarishKumar - never heard of `pgfinterruptboundingbox` before; thankfully I don't have any content in those nodes that I want to avoid, so this approach works for me ... cheers!

Comment: @sdaau Glad it helped. Have a nice day. :)

Comment: `overlay` option to the node should do the same effect.

Comment: @percusse True and I will add a note. Thanks :)