# Linespacing with cutwin

Tags: paragraphs, line-spacing, tufte, wrap, cutwin

The problem is that the first and the last lines have different line spacing compared with the rest of the text.
This is the code:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{tufte-book}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}
\usepackage[OT1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{euler,beton}
\usepackage{tikz,tkz-euclide}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetkzobj{all}
\usetikzlibrary{fpu}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\usepackage{cutwin}

\geometry{
  paperwidth=145mm,
  paperheight=215mm,
  inner=16mm,
  outer=10mm,
  top=10mm,
  bottom=40mm,
  marginparsep=5mm,
  marginparwidth=40mm,
  includemp,
  includehead
}


\usepackage[nopar]{lipsum}
\usepackage{xstring}
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/26808/2595
\makeatletter
\def\unpacklipsum#1#2#3{%
  \count@=#1\relax
  \advance\count@\m@ne
  \def#3{}%
  \loop\ifnum\count@<#2\relax
    \advance\count@\@ne
    \edef#3{#3\csname lipsum@\romannumeral\count@\endcsname}%
  \repeat}
\makeatother

\def\loremnchars[#1]#2{%
  \unpacklipsum{#1}{#1}{\myunpacked}%
  \StrMid{\myunpacked}{1}{#2}% same as \StrLeft{\myunpacked}{#2}
}


\begin{document}

\loremnchars[1]{255}

\opencutright
\begin{shapedcutout}{2}{16}{0.90\textwidth, 0.79\textwidth,0.7\textwidth, 0.65\textwidth,0.61\textwidth, 0.6\textwidth, 0.55\textwidth, 0.58\textwidth, 0.58\textwidth, 0.58\textwidth, 0.6\textwidth,0.61\textwidth, 0.65\textwidth,0.7\textwidth, 0.79\textwidth,0.90\textwidth}
\loremnchars[1]{600}
\end{shapedcutout}


\begin{marginfigure}[-8.5cm]

    {\caption{ }\label{Brahmagupta1}}
    \rightline{\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
        %=============================
        \tkzInit[xmin=-0.5, xmax=6.6, ymin=-5, ymax=2.5]
        \tkzClip
        %==========================================   
        \tkzDefPoints{0/0/A, 2.5/2/B, 6/0/C}
        \tkzDefLine[orthogonal=through B](C,A) \tkzGetPoint{t}
        \tkzInterLL(B,t)(C,A) \tkzGetPoint{P}
        \tkzCircumCenter(A,B,C)\tkzGetPoint{O}
        \tkzInterLC(t,B)(O,A) \tkzGetPoints{D}{a}
        \tkzDefMidPoint(A,D) \tkzGetPoint{T}
        \tkzInterLL(T,P)(C,B) \tkzGetPoint{F}
        %==================================================
        \tkzDrawPolygon[very thick](A,B,C,D)
        \tkzDrawCircle(O,A)
        \tkzDrawSegments(A,C B,D T,F)
        %\tkzFillPolygon[color = gray,opacity=0.3](C,T,F)
        %================================================      
        \tkzLabelPoint[left](A){$A$}
        \tkzLabelPoint[above](B){$B$}
        \tkzLabelPoint[right](C){$C$}
        \tkzLabelPoint[below](D){$D$}
        \tkzLabelPoint[above left](P){$P$}
        \tkzLabelPoint[below left](T){$T$}
        \tkzLabelPoint[above right](F){$F$}
        \tkzMarkRightAngle[size=0.2](C,P,D);
        \tkzMarkRightAngle[size=0.2](P,F,C);
        \tkzLabelAngle[pos=0.4](T,A,P){$\alpha$}
        \tkzLabelAngle[pos=-0.4](T,P,A){$\alpha$}
        \tkzLabelAngle[pos=0.4](C,P,F){$\alpha$}
        \tkzLabelAngle[pos=0.4](P,B,F){$\alpha$}
        \tkzLabelAngle[pos=0.5](T,P,D){$\beta$}
        \tkzLabelAngle[pos=0.7](P,D,T){$\beta$}
        \tkzLabelAngle[pos=0.5](F,P,B){$\beta$}
        \tkzLabelAngle[pos=0.8](F,C,P){$\beta$}
        \tkzMarkSegment[pos=0.5, mark=|](A,T)
        \tkzMarkSegment[pos=0.5, mark=|](T,D)
        %============================================      
        \tkzDrawPoints(A,B,C,D,P,T,F)
        \end{tikzpicture}}
\end{marginfigure}
\loremnchars[1]{255}
\end{document}
```

This is the output:
[image]
[image]
You can see a distinct overlap on the first picture. It is not that visible on the 2nd one, but it is there. The first overlap can be fixed maually by inserting something like `\bigskip` in between the parafrphs, but how to tuckle the 2nd one?

Comment: Try to add `\vspace{0.5\baselineskip}` in `shapedcutout` environment

Comment: The problem moves one line higher

Comment: Actually I changed the shape of the aragraph playing with the lengths of the lines, so now the paragraph ends with picture. It serves my problem but doesn't resolve the issue.